# R - deleting rows from data.frame

Tags: r, if-statement, delete-row

I am very new to r an programming and have a basic question (my first one on stackoverflow :) )
I want to delete some rows from a data.frame and use an if-statement on that account.
My code is running but it is unfortunately not deleting the correct rows but instead every second row of my dataframe I think.

"myDataVergleich" is the name of my data.frame. "myData$QUESTNNR" is the column by which is decided whether the row is supposed to stay in the dataframe or not.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(myDataVergleich))
  {if(myData$QUESTNNR[i] != "t0_mathe" | myData$QUESTNNR[i] != "t0_bio" | myData$QUESTNNR[i] != "t0_allg2" |
     myData$QUESTNNR[i] != "t7_mathe_Version1" | myData$QUESTNNR[i] != "t7_bio_Version1") 
    {myDataVergleich <- myDataVergleich[-c(i),] }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. From your question it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. What values of QUESTNNR do you want to see removed?

Comment: `if` is not vectorized in R. Learn to use vectorized functions such as a "naked" `!=` or `grepl` for indexing and selection.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow and to R. I think your intuition is correct but there are some issues. First, you say your data is called 'myDataVergleich' but inside your loop you are accessing 'myData'. So you might need to change 'myData$QUESTNNR[i]' to 'myDataVergleich$QUESTNNR[i]' in the loop.

A great thing about R is that there are solutions people have figured out already for many problems, sub-setting a data frame by a condition is one of them. You should look into the tidyverse family of packages, especially dplyr in this case.

```
install.packages('dplyr')
install.packages('magrittr')
```

If you want to keep the rows with these strings this code will work

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
strings <- c(
  "t0_mathe", "t0_bio", "t0_allg2", "t7_mathe_Version1", "t7_bio_Version1"
)
filtered_data <- myDataVergleich %>%
  dplyr::filter(QUESTNNR %in% strings)
```

If you want to keep the rows that don't contain these strings this code will work

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
strings <- c(
  "t0_mathe", "t0_bio", "t0_allg2", "t7_mathe_Version1", "t7_bio_Version1"
)
filtered_data <- myDataVergleich %>%
  dplyr::filter(!QUESTNNR %in% strings)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you very much! This worked out very well :)
Do you also have a tipp how I could filter only parts of a string, instead of a whole string? But still do this for several parts of strings?
Thank!

Comment: Glad it worked. please upvote the answer so that others with the same question know that answer will solve their problem. Can you give a me a little more detail and perhaps an example of what you need on this new question, your comment is a little vague, I'm not sure exactly what you need. thanks.

Comment: I just tried to upvote. I hope it worked :)
About my other question: In my post before I was trying to detect a complete string in my dataframe. But I am also trying to filter only by part of strings.  E. g. filter als rows that contain "bio" instead of seperately filtering "t0_bio", "t1_bio" etc.

Comment: Also I had another problem with your code: with this part "!QUESTNNR" because it returned the error message that logical operators only apply to numerics, complex and logicaIs. But QUESTNNR contains strings of course...

Comment: I would have to know the error, QUESTNNR %in% strings returns a TRUE or FALSE and adding the ! just returns the opposite, so that should word fine. You can detect part of a string with str_detect from the 'stringr' package.

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(x = c('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '0')) 
df %>% dplyr::filter(str_detect(x, 'l'))

Answer (score 0):

I would have to know the error, QUESTNNR %in% strings returns a TRUE or FALSE and adding the ! just returns the opposite, so that should word fine. You can detect part of a string with str_detect from the 'stringr' package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
df <- tibble(x = c('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '0')) 
df %>% dplyr::filter(str_detect(x, 'l'))
```